# how to make flake8 ignore ipdb imports?

Tags: python, flake8, ipdb

I'm trying to clean flake8 errors from my code, and I have an `ipdb` import which should stay there.

I tried:

```
  import ipdb  # noqa: F811
  import ipdb  # NOQA 
  import ipdb  # noqa
```

But all give the same error: `- ipdb imported`

How can I make it go away? (I don't want to ignore it entirely, as I don't want any other `ipdb` imports in the code, only to allow this one)

***EDIT***: I may have been wrong. I now suspect this is not Flake8 related, but `debug-statements` pre-commit hook related.

Comment: Do you mean `F401 'ipdb' imported but unused`?

Comment: no, because it is used. I'm not sure it is a Flake8 error anymore...

Answer (score 1):

yeah that's output from debug-statements, it intentionally has no way to disable it's behavior as the intention is to *prevent* checking in debug statements

that said, you can trick it:

```
ipdb = __import__('ipdb')
```

disclaimer: I'm the author of pre-commit and pre-commit-hooks (and the debug-statements hook there) and the maintainer of flake8